# I want to formulate a more advanced sentence in German describing why I want to take an English course

Tags: translation, english-to-german, phrase, style

I want to write a letter for a language school and to ask them about the English courses they offer. I need a course to improve my English for sending Emails and making telephone calls (Work reasons). 
I made a try and it looks like this:

> Ich würde im nächsten Jahr einen Englischkurs bei Ihnen besuchen, denn mein Job erfordert sehr gute Englischkenntnisse für geschäftliche E-Mails und Telefonate zu haben.

Would this expression "aus geschäftlichen Gründen, geschäftliche E-Mails schreiben, Telefonate annehmen usw" fulfill the purpose?

If you have any Ideas, write them please.

Comment: The question would be OK if it were about taking a German course. Just kidding. It would also be off-topic.

Answer (score 3):

Other than the typo, it's a proper sentence.
Still it's a bit stiff (but not wrong!).

I'd write:

*Ich möchte* (a tad more polite and binding. *würde* sounds too optional) *im nächsten Jahr einen Englischkurs bei Ihnen besuchen, denn mein Job erfordert sehr gute Englischkenntnisse für geschäftliche E-Mails und Telefonate.*

Comment: I would avoid the word *Job* in almost all circumstances. *Job* in German sounds like something you do without any comitment. A *Job* (in German) you do only, and only, in order to earn some money, but you would leave it as soon as possible. Better say: *in meinem Beruf*... Of course you can be working in such a *Job*, but as you consider learning English for it, this is unlikely.